# SQL Block Grant Execute to All Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-grant

I know the method of granting a User/Role permission to execute all stored procedures within a database.  Is there a way to prevent this while allowing someone to grant execute permissions to individual stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

Yup.

Short answer:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON <schemaName>.<procName> TO <userOrRoleName>;
```

Full discussion of options: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19749/how-do-you-grant-execute-permission-for-a-single-stored-procedure

It's the step I almost always forget when a service account needs access to a new proc.

Comment: Thanks but this isn't exactly what I'm looking for.  I know how to grant execute to a single procedure; I'm trying to figure out how to prevent someone from granting execute to all procedures while allowing them to grant execute on a single stored procedure.